# react-navigate stackNavigator backtracks to different screen than what lead there

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using react-navigation (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html) and have a navigation setup of the form:

```
bottomTabNavigator
    stackNavigatorA
        screenA1
        screenA2
        (with initialRouteName=screenA1)
    stackNavigatorB
        screenB1
        screenB2
        screenB3
        screenB4
        (with initialRouteName=screenB1)
```

screenA1 basically looks like

```
<View>
<Button title='to A2' onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('screenA2')}/>
</View>
```

and screenA2

```
<View>
<Button title='to B3' onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB3')}/>
</View>
```

while the B screens look like

```
// screenB1
<View>
<Button title='to B2' onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB2')}/>
</View>

// screenB2
<View>
<Button title='to B3' onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB3')}/>
</View>

// screenB3
<View>
<Button title='to B4' onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('screenB4')}/>
</View>

// screenB4
<View>
</View>
```

With this setup, I can navigate from B1->B2->B3->B4 and back down the stack successfully and can navigate from A1->A2 and back down successfully. But when trying to navigate from A1->A2->B3 (or ->B4) and back, it ends up taking the path A1 to A2 to B3 backtrack B1 (rather than back to A2). Even adding `<Button title='FIXME: goback workaround' onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.goBack()}}/>` to screenB3 does not help (here I was expecting it to then go back to whatever the previous screen was).

Could someone explain why this happens? Don't understand what `this.props.navigation.navigate()` is doing in this scenario? Anything about this in the docs? I would think that using the default back buttons would just go in reverse through the stack that was used to arrive at any given screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**:

Ended up creating a seperate nav. menu

```
stackNavigatorB'
       screenB3
       screenB4
```

so have setup of form

```
stackNavigatorA
        screenA1,
        screenA2,
        stackNavigatorB'

 stackNavigatorB
        screenB1,
        screenB2,
        stackNavigatorB'
```

which lets me go back and forth between stacknavigatorA and B, using the B3 and B4 screen for different data in each stack independently.

**Other things tried and failed (for info purposes)**:

- When using goBack(), it goes back to the previous route in that stack.
  Using this.props.navigation.navigate allows you to go to any screen, but if you move from a screen from stack A to a screen from stack B, using goBack will return the previous route **in your stack B**. Looking at the docs (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#docsNav), I had initially thought that it meant 'the stack that was being created as user navigated through the different stack cards' (ie. going back would go back to the card the user was just looking at previously). This does not mean that the stacks are totally isolated, but means you can't use goBack or push if you want to navigate between different stacks. `goBack` and `Push` **follow a stack flow**, while `navigate` allows you to go to any screen regardless of their route.

  - Think of it this way: navigate is global, while push and goBack are "subnavigation", they don't operate on the same scope. If you navigate to a screen belonging to another stack and you want to go back, you could still record your navigation and navigate to previous route name (using a custom function to track it, or navigation state management). You can't just use the built-in goBack function because it serves a different purpose.
- Setting the navigators to look like

  stackNavigatorA[
          screenA1,
          screenA2,
          screenB3,
          screenB4]

  stackNavigatorB[
          screenB1,
          screenB2,
          screenB3,
          screenB4]

  I still get the behavior where  going back from B3 (no matter whether I got there from A1 or B1) takes me all the way back to B1. I would think now that the stack could navigate to all of their assigned screens and goBack() the way they came without interacting with each other (when simply using the default back button to trace back 'down' the stack), since they'd be using this 'subnavigation' within the screens assigned in their own stack (as mentioned in the previous bullet point).

  - As it has been explained to me: this.props.navigation.push and this.props.navigation.goBack are meant to be used for navigating inside the same stack. Duplicating screens will not change this behavior. If you need to go back and forth between screens from different stacks, you should be using .navigation. You can build your own dispatch actions with NavigationOptions, and keep track of your navigation (ie store your routes in your store, and have your own goBack function navigating to the previous route). This may have been the nicer way to do it if was using redux at the time. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html

** Some parts of this answer were from a discussion in the react-navigate discord chat.